# http://url.ru/ => http://url.ru/

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

**Пример**

Допустим, у нас есть код:

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Сайт</th><th>Название</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>http://url.ru/</td><td>Сайт 1</td></tr><tr><td>http://url1.ru/</td><td>Сайт 2</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Естественно, значений в первом столбце ("Сайт") типа url.ru и url1.ru - может быть очень много и все они могут быть разные (т.е. не только url.ru, но и vasya.ru и petya.ru и т.д. и т.п.).

Должно получиться на выходе примерно следующее:

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Сайт</th><th>Название</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td><a href="http://url.ru/" target="_blank">http://url.ru/</a></td><td>Сайт 1</td></tr><tr><td><a href="http://url1.ru/" target="_blank">http://url1.ru/</a></td><td>Сайт 2</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

**Описание**

Т.е., нужно сделать так, чтобы все значения в первом столбце заменялись так:

```
Значение => <a href="Значение" target="_blank">Значение</a>
```

Т.к. я не силён в Javascript, прошу дать хотя бы примерный код, как такое реализовать, либо дать необходимые ссылки для изучения функций, которые способны реализовать данную задачу. Конечно же, если Вам не сложно. :)

Comment: @nick777, человеческим языком, Вам нужно делать ссылки активными. Верно?

Comment: Верно. Все ссылки находятся в первом столбце таблицы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Окей, всё на самом деле просто.

Для начала, вам надо найти таблицу. Для этого лучше всего дать ей `id` и сказать

```
var tab = document.getElementById("тут ваш id");
```

Затем, надо обойти все ячейки первого столбца. Пройдёмся по строкам:

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = tab.rows[i]; i++)
{
```

... получим первую клетку:

```
    var cell = row.cells[0];
```

... и заменим содержимое:

```
    var oldText = cell.innerHTML;
    cell.innerHTML = "<a href='" + oldText + "' target='_blank'>" +
                     oldText + "</a>";
}
```

Вроде всё.

Стиль, конечно, напоминает C, может быть кто-нибудь приведёт более идиоматичное решение.

---

Обновление:
на самом деле надо итерировать только внутри tbody. Делаем так:

```
var tab = document.getElementById("тут ваш id");
for (var j = 0, body; body = tab.tBodies[j]; j++)
{
    for (var i = 0, row; row = body.rows[i]; i++)
    {
        var cell = row.cells[0];
        var oldText = cell.innerHTML;
        cell.innerHTML = "<a href='" + oldText + "' target='_blank'>" +
                     oldText + "</a>";
    }
}
```

У кого-то есть красивое решение с select'ом на jQuery?

---

Сам разобрался и придумал на jQuery. Оказывается, jQuery ого-го.

```
$('#ваш_id td:first-child').each(function(i) {
    var oldText = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("<a href='" + oldText + "' target='_blank'>" +
                     oldText + "</a>");
});
```